# SQL - How can I filter a table by a column which is an array?

Tags: sql

I would like to filter a table depending on an array type of column.

So It is a contacts table which have a column of sms. What I want to do is select all non US numbers from their contacts. So I should filter everything that does not start with '1'. I kind of thought that to do this I should query it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM contacts
WHERE CAST (array_to_string(sms, ',', '*') as varchar) NOT LIKE '1%'
```

But What happened was it only returned the accounts with contacts that are non US in their first numbers. But I want to filter the accounts that have a number in the 2nd or nth element.

example:

```
contact {
 id:123
 name: Churva
 sms: {13131313131, 113131444, 2341414141}
}
```

This should be filtered too since it has a non US number in the tip.

Is there a way to do this in SQL Query?

Comment: what sql plateform are you using Bon Andre?

Comment: I am doing this with PostGreSQL

Comment: Please provide your table structures, relationships, etc to be able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Just need to do this in one table. the structure is just simple, it is only name, id, and numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to do this using this code:

SELECT
   *

```
FROM
   contacts
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT
    FROM unnest(sms) pNumber 
    WHERE pNumber LIKE '1%'
)
```

[image]

Is this the right way of doing this? Though I got the right results not really sure if this is the standard way of doing this.